# PowerShell which exception to catch

Tags: powershell

I have the following exception:

```
New-PSDrive : The user name or password is incorrect
At C:\Users\t\Desktop\a\b.ps1:23 char:22
+ ...    $Drive = New-PSDrive -Name "T" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\$ 
...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (T:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
```

How do I figure out which exception I should be catching in a try-catch block?

Comment: Generate the error & run this $error[0].exception.gettype().fullname